# Heroku incorrectly reports a model validation error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I'm a newbie developing a rails app. I pushed the master to Heroku and ran "git heroku run rake db:migrate" without problems.

The app runs great locally, but on Heroku a "duration" field in one of my tables erroneously reports an error indicating that it "can not be blank" even though I pass it a valid value per the model's validation. This behavior only occurs on Heroku.  Locally, the "presence" validation behaves as expected.  Heroku does not indicate any problen with my database schema, but it appears something may be wrong in the database. That's my hunch, but I don't know.

To troubleshoot:  I reset the Heroku database by running "heroku pg:reset DATABASE" and then ran "heruko run rake db:migrate". Those commands did not solve the problem.

I don't know how to troubleshoot further.  Any thoughts, suggestions or ideas?  I'm running SQLite3 in my development & testing environments with pg on Heroku.  I haven't made any unusual SQLite migrations.  I do plan to get rid of SQLite3 and go with pg entirely, but I need to solve this problem first.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Use Postgres locally too and you will be able to debug the problem.

Comment: What does the column look like? What are you trying to put in the column? What does the validation look like? The first step to solving your problem is probably replacing SQLite with PostgreSQL BTW, that's not something that should come later.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but the "problem" appears to have "fixed" itself.  I shut everything off last night; this morning Heroku has no problems with the column.  No errorrs; everything works as expected. Nevertheless, I will switch exclusively to postgres for my app. It may "work" now, but this has taught me a valuable lesson (different databases handle SQL differently).  It's probably best to use the same database for development & production.  I'm learning the ropes with Rails, but I won't ever forget that lesson!  Once again, thanks for responding.